# Update Command Requires a Valid insertCommand when passed DataRow

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

I am having problem while executing the following code. Using Ngpsql Data Adapter. The function takes the datatable creates and update query

Parameter string values are dynamically generated update values which are then concatenated with the Local Variable String Query and creates a query like
UPDATE xyz SET ecode=@ecode,name=@name ..... and so on

```
public void TransactionRecording(DataTable DT, string values,bool update)
    {            
        string Query = "";
        NpgsqlDataAdapter NgAdapter = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();

        if (update)
        {
            Query += "UPDATE Cards SET " + values;
            NgAdapter.UpdateCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(Query, connection);
            this.UpdateParameterSetForLocalToCentral(NgAdapter);

        }
        else
        {
            Query += "INSERT INTO Cards (ecode, ename, fname, address1, address2, address3, deo, employee, active, birth, type, company, Designation, photo, manual, visit_to, visit_name, vehicle, modifideby, registered, validity, tpl, serial, gateno, level, gate_in, gate_out) VALUES(" + values + ")";
            NgAdapter.InsertCommand = new NpgsqlCommand(Query, connection);
            this.InsertParameterSetForLocalToCentral(NgAdapter);
        }


        try { 
            NgAdapter.Update(DT); }catch(Exception ex)
        {    
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }


    }

    public void UpdateParameterSetForLocalToCentral(NpgsqlDataAdapter NgAdapter)
    {

        foreach (string name in Enum.GetNames(typeof(LocalToCentralFields)))
        {
            switch (name)
            {
                case "ecode":
                case "ename":
                case "fname":
                case "address1":
                case "address2":
                case "address3":
                case "type":
                case "company":
                case "Designation":
                case "visit_to":
                case "visit_name":
                case "vehicle":
                case "modifideby":                   
                case "serial":
                case "gateno":
                case "level":
                case "gate_in":
                case "gate_out":
                     NpParam = NgAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@"+name,NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar);
                     break;
                case "deo":
                case "employee":
                case "active":
                     NpParam = NgAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + name, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Boolean);
                     break;
                case "birth":
                case "registered":
                case "validity":
                     NpParam = NgAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + name, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Timestamp);
                     break;
                case "photo":
                case "tpl":
                     NpParam = NgAdapter.UpdateCommand.Parameters.Add("@" + name, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Bytea);
                     break;

            }
           NpParam.SourceVersion = DataRowVersion.Original;
           NpParam.SourceColumn = "ecode";

        }

    }
```

getting this error Update Command requires a Valid InsertCommand when passed a DataRow, well I am updating the rows then why asking for the insert command please help

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

When you call `NgAdapter.Update`, it calls appropriate commands for each row of the DataTable depending of rowState of the row. If rowState is inserted, it calls for `InsertCommand`, if rowState is Deleted, it calls for `DeleteCommand`, so you have to define all commands in your DataAdapter

Comment: Now I have created an insert command as its written in the above code but now its saying the column doesnt exists ? what seems to be the problem but the column is there in the table of database

Comment: ok I sorted out i was missing adding the parameters for the insert query. Ok here is another error which i got . saying duplicate key violates unique constraint "PK_Cards" so the ecode column is the primary key I have created the update command and insert command i want to update the existing one in the database if not found insert it, I populated the data for the update of the fields not to insert the updated fields in the database

Comment: My logic is simple Select data from local server a table name Cards the check the each card in central server if found create a datatable to update the fields of central server as if local server has changed some information of that record according to the primrary key .. if no data found on central server then create a new datatable and insert it in database . but at first my function worked fine when no records found on the central server it inserted the 100 records. to check the update of the fields but it started inserting again and as primary key constraint its not working

Comment: Do you have primary key set in your DataTable?